# django, distinct() not behaving

Tags: python, django

For some reason duplicate values aren't eliminated.

```
records = Records.objects.all()
records2 = records.values_list('columna','columna').distinct()
print records2
```

I must be doing something stupid

Comment: Do you use any `order_by`? maybe you have set a default ordering in the model's `Meta` class? See the note here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: I don't think I'm using django-pyodbc.  I'm using mysql.

Comment: I'm not using any order_by in my query.  I did use a filter.  And I did specify a default ordering

Comment: I see the note specifically, "The moral here is that if you are using distinct() be careful about ordering by related models. Similarly, when using distinct() and values() together, be careful when ordering by fields not in the values() call."  However, they don't give a solution.

Comment: Try to output the sql generated by your query: `print records2.query`, maybe this gives you a clue whats going wrong!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to cast the values_list to a set (to remove duplicates) then back to a list

Comment: Converting the entire result set to a set and then back to a list will incur a lot more overhead than a distinct query (using an index!). If the result set is very large, you could run into pretty big problems. If the result set (total, not distinct) is small, the difference would probably be negligible. Something to be aware of..